# Overhead video camera to capture live video to a PC

Tags: windows, video, webcam, streaming, camera

Can anyone recommend a manufacturer or starting point for overhead video camera units that can be used to capture a Microsoft [Surface](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/) application in use? I'd like to stream this from another PC but I'm not sure what the best camera to look at would be. It seems like some of the overhead security cameras would fit the requirements but I don't know if they will interface easily with a PC.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is any standard webcam (for good quality, I recommend an HD one such as the [Microsoft Lifecam HD range](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/digitalcommunication/Productlist.aspx?type=LifeCam), then just look at getting a good rig set up - or even stick and mount to the ceiling.

After this, the camera should be detected by the machine as a standard webcam and available as a normal resource. For streaming, take a look at web based services such as [Ustream](http://www.ustream.tv/) or using something such as [Microsoft Media Encoder](http://www.microsoft.com/WINDOWS/WINDOWSMEDIA/FORPROS/ENCODER/DEFAULT.MSPX) and a Windows Server that runs the Media Streaming role.

You could even just use any video camera and get someone on a ladder to hold it - then transfer it to pc later if you do not require it live.

However, in all honestly, I think that you are looking more for a rig / mount than any sort of special camera.